# How to generate OAuth token efficiently

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, access-token

I want to fetch data from the application where it uses OAuth token for authentication via API.

Generated OAuth token is valid for 30 days. After that I have to generate new token.

Currently I am generating OAuth token for each request to the application (internal project) before making each request as below

```
def generate_token
end

def get(path)
  generate_token
end

def fetch_customer_details
  get(path)
end

def fetch_employee_details
  get(path)
end
```

How can I avoid generating token for each request and make the request to fetch data without authorisation issue?

Answer (score 0):

You need to store the token somewhere in between requests, and fetch that value (instead of generating new token). Probably the best way is to use Session for this:

```
def generate_token
  session[:oauth_token] = generate_your_actual_token
end

def get(path)
  session[:oauth_token] || generate_token
end

def fetch_customer_details
  get(path)
end

def fetch_employee_details
  get(path)
end
```

Comment: Token will expire after 30 days. Will it generate token after 30 days of expiry and use it?

Comment: well... that's a different question... I haven't seen any attempt yet to actually generate an OAuth token...this is just about storing and fetching it from a session. The session itself is only valid during the same visit. So if someone doesn't stay on your site for 30 straight days, you don't have to worry.